# How does the << Operator exactly work?

Tags: c++

I have some problems in understanding the << operator.

If I have:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
//...

int t = 5;
cout << "test is: " << t << endl;
```

Now the function operator<< is called.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, string* s)
{
    return out << s << endl;
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, int* value)
{
    return out << value << endl;
}
```

the string-pointer points to the address with value *test is:* but to what does the element `out` refer (to `cout`?)? and is the function body of ostream& correct in that way?

Thank you so much for any explanation.

Comment: Might helpyou to see `cout << "test" << t` as equivalent to `operator<<(operator<<(cout, "test"), t)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's fix your code: the operators should be taking `const` references or values instead of pointers:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const string& s) // const reference
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, int i)           // value
```

Now to your question: you are correct, the `out` parameter receives the reference to the `cout`, or whatever is the `ostream&` returned from the expression on the left side of `<<`. The expression on the left of `<<` is not necessarily `cout`, though - other common cases are results of other `<<` operators<sup>*</sup> for chaining, and stream manipulators. In all cases these expressions return a reference to `ostream` so that the "chain" could continue.

<sup>*</sup> The reason the `operator<<` return an `ostream&` is so that you could chain the output. In overwhelming number of cases you wold return the same `ostream&` that you receive as the first parameter, although there is no limitation on the part of the standard C++ library requiring you to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. It's `int` not `int*`, and `char const*` not `string*`.

`out`, of course, refers to `std::cout` in this example. What else would it be?

And no those bodies are not correct in the slightest — they attempt to reinvoke themselves infinitely, and do nothing else.

Comment: You mean [`char const*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) as the parameter?

Comment: @Columbo: Suppose so, yeah (27.7.3.6.4)

Comment: i cant see why they reinvoke themselves infinitely. Because if you overload the operator, you write: return out << v.a <<"/" << v.b; and there is no self invocation. The function body is not necessary, but it should work as an explanation for myself. (parallel to operator-overloading to understand the functionality better)

Answer (score 0):

```
int t = 5;
cout << "test is: " << t << endl;
```

First call would be to:-

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const char* str)
```

out = cout

str = "test is: "

Second call would be applied on object returned by first call which is `ostream`.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, int x)
```

out = cout

x = t